# How to write on an Excel sheet

Tags: c#

i am trying to write the data on a cell using using microsoft office interop excel, but in the end it gives me an error. I want to save the changes in the same file i am using to read,not to create a new one.I have been trying and reading so many and yet the problem is the same.The error is :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'We can't save 'email list.xlsx' because the file is read-only.
```

My code is:

```
        static void openFile()
        {
            Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
            string path_of_file = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Source\\Repos\\IC.EmailCheck\\IC.MailCheck\\email list.xlsx";
            Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path_of_file);
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
            int column_of_final_email = 4;
            transform_excelsheet_to_matrix(range, column_of_final_email, worksheet, workbook, application);
        }
        static void transform_excelsheet_to_matrix(Excel.Range range, int column_of_final_email, Excel.Worksheet worksheet, Excel.Workbook workbook, Excel.Application application)
        {
            string[,] arr = new string[range.Rows.Count, range.Columns.Count];
            for (int row = 1; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                List<string> list_of_information_in_excel = new List<string>();
                for (int coll = 1; coll <= 3; coll++)
                {
                    arr[row - 1, coll - 1] = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, coll]).Text;
                    list_of_information_in_excel.Add(arr[row - 1, coll - 1]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                var full_name_in_first_col_in_excel = list_of_information_in_excel[0];//.Replace(" ", "");
                var website_domain_in_excel = list_of_information_in_excel[2];
                Console.WriteLine(full_name_in_first_col_in_excel);
                Console.WriteLine(website_domain_in_excel);
                printFullname_domain_and_clear_array(full_name_in_first_col_in_excel, website_domain_in_excel, list_of_information_in_excel);
                //string checked_email = do_checks_of_email(full_name_in_first_col_in_excel, website_domain_in_excel);
                worksheet.Cells[row, column_of_final_email] = website_domain_in_excel;
                application.Visible = false;
                application.UserControl = false;
                workbook.Save(); //here it stops
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *using microsoft office interop excel* - prefer npoi, closedxml, openxml, epplus or literally anything else..

Comment: `Workbooks.Open()` has several arguments, ensure you refer the documentation and pass all relevant values.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is very clear: the file where you're trying to write is read-only... so it is not possible to write on it.